I have problem with my react native fitness app where I have fetch for food database that works on PC but doesn't work on apk
const fetchData = async () => {
try {
const response = await fetch(
`http://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?app_id=181e5eb4&app_key=key&ingr=${food}
                       &nutrition-type=cooking&181e5eb4=0633a8e3dc27c8ba43caf5b67709cd32`
  );
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  setDataPerServing(jsonData);
  setData(jsonData.parsed[0].food);
  setVisible("inline");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("There was an error fetching the data:", error);
}
};

This fetch is called by button and for some reason it works on expo go but not on exported apk.
Googled and searched on internet.
